# how to fetch parts of url in javascript

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a url like this: http://localhost/something/de/

The last one is the language code de for German. I want to fetch it using javascript. The link may also become like this: http://localhost/something/de/node/artist/117/author/98, in that case how do I fetch the language part.

Actually I want to set up placeholder using javascript, I got the help for placeholder but I dont get how to fetch the language part from url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in jQuery, just get the url and then split as required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $url = window.location.pathname;
});
```